# What is the lifespan of a static variable

Tags: java, static

In the following code, does `Nail`'s reference to `ypaw` end as soon as I exit the method `someMethod` or is there potential for leakage? Also, once I exit class `Dog` are all references to `ypaw` gone or does the static reference inside Nail cause troubles? Note that `ypaw` and `mPaw` are the same object and I am wondering how long the object lives in memory due to the static reference. Of course assume the Garbage Collector executes at the appropriate time.

```
Class Dog{

  private Paw ypaw;
  //…..

  public void someMethod(){
    Nail nail = Nail.getInstance(ypaw);
  }
}


Class Nail{
  private static Paw mPaw;

  public static Nail getInstance(Paw p){
    mPaw = p;
    return new Nail();
  }
  //…. other stuff
}
```

**Edit**

I mean to say that I have a single instance of Dog as `myDog` and that my single instance of `Nail` is through `myDog`. What happens to `mPaw` after `myDog` dies (i.e. is gc'ed)?

Comment: You don't _exit_ a class.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis so does that mean once I assign an object to the static variable, that object lives beyond the death of the parent objects? i.e. mPaw would live on beyond Nail and Dog even if those two were the only ones using `ypaw`?

Comment: `mPaw` belongs to the class, it's a class variable. The object it references will be potentially eligible for GC when the class is GC'ed. That won't typically ever happen in a Java application. You can set the variable to null to achieve similar behavior.

Comment: @learner What is a Nail?  What is Nail.mPaw?  Your code appears to be able to construct Nail objects, n1, n2, n3..., but all of those objects share the same _static_ mPaw variable (static means, there is only one).  Are you trying to say that every Nail that is ever created must "belong to" the same Paw? (or "connect to", or "relate to" or...)  'Cause that's what it looks like.  That's what "static" means.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, a static variable lives for as long as the classloader which loaded the class does. So that's "forever" in many applications.

It's not clear what you're trying to achieve, but this code is almost certainly a bad idea.

(In general, mutable static data is a bad idea. And mutable static non-private fields are a *really* bad idea - you can't possibly control all access for synchronization purposes, apart from anything else.)

Comment: image all references to Paw are private. does that make any difference? My particular application is to have an android activity pass a variable to a fragment. But essentially it is what you see, except for making the fields private. Thanks for any additional advice you can give.

Comment: You are technically correct. The best kind of correct.

Comment: @keyser I don't understand the comment. Will you please elaborate? Who is correct? What is correct?

Comment: @learner I was referring to Jon Skeets answer. [Source](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hou0lU8WMgo).

Comment: See my edit, if that makes a difference: I mean to say that I have a single instance of Dog as myDog and that my single instance of Nail is through myDog. What happens to mPaw after myDog dies?

Comment: @learner: It's *better*, in that you can make sure that you synchronize all access to the static fields. But it sounds like you need to differentiate between *variables* and *objects*. Both `mPaw` and `myDog` are variables. Both can have a reference to the same object, but the object will only be garbage collected when there are no *live* references left. If one variable goes out of scope (or whatever), that has no bearing whatsoever on other variables which happen to refer to the same object.

Comment: Sorry if I seem slow. I just want to make sure I get it. So what you are saying is that the static reference in my particular case is irrelevant. Once I exit `someMethod` then variable `mPow` cannot hold the object back. (I only make it static because that's the only way to pass it through getInstance).

Comment: @learner: What do you mean by "hold the object back"? The `mPaw` certainly *will* stop the object that its value refers to from being garbage collected.

Comment: @learner:  Jon Skeet said "[learn the difference] between variables and objects."  Your variable, Nail.mpaw does not refert to _ypaw_.  ypaw is a variable, and variables can never refer to other variables.  Nail.mpaw refers to a Paw _object_:  Specifically, it refers to the _same_ Paw object that d.ypaw referenced whenever d.someMethod() was last called for any Dog d.  So long as it is not changed again, it will continue to refer to that same Paw object even after d has been garbage collected, and that reference will prevent the Paw object itself from being garbage collected.

Comment: @jameslarge I understand. My re-statement was that since Nail has one instance, the one inside `someMethod`, once the code exits `someMethod` then whereas Nail's single instance is now dead, then Nail's reference to the Paw object that ypaw happens to be pointing to should be gone SO THAT once the single Dog object is in turn cg'ed then there should have no reference to **that** Paw object left. Therefore, once the `myDog` object is dead then so is the Paw object that was being pointed to by ypaw and mPaw.

Comment: @jameslarge but I do get it now, the Paw object pointed to by `mPaw` will die once all the references to Nail are gone as the classLoader will have no reason to keep the Paw object in memory.

Comment: @learner: Well the `mPaw` variable will *have* a reference to the instance, unless you change the value of the variable. So no, in your example the `Paw` object would *not* be garbage collected.

Comment: @learner, The class loader is only indirectly related to what keeps the Paw object alive.  An object is _live_ if it is referenced by any variable on the stack of any running thread, or by any static variable of any live class, or by any instance variable of any _live_ object.  Your Paw object is live because of the reference from Nail.mPaw and, Your Nail class is live because it is referenced by its class loader, and that happens to be the default class loader, then it will stay in memory until the JVM shuts down because the default class loader is kept alive by the JVM itself.